# packets compared to frames (osi)

Tags: networking, packets, osi

This is my first question here so sorry if something isn't pretty or badly written.

but i've been learning about the osi model for some time now and i can't find a good indepth explanation about frames (in the data-link layer) and what is the difference between frames and packets?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames are what layer-2 protocols encapsulate layer-3 packets in. The layer-3 packet header will have the source and destination layer-3 addresses, and the layer-2 frame header will have the layer-2 source and destination addresses. The same holds true for layer-4 segments, which are encapsulated by layer-3 packets. The layer-4 segment header will have the layer-4 source and destination addresses.

Layer-2 frames are used to deliver data on a LAN; layer-3 packets deliver data between LANs; layer-4 segments deliver data between applications.